# Mongodb - How to create full text index for a JSON field?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

This question is about creating full text index for a mongo db collection.

The collection contains documents like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b44cd9dec97d60001efb75d"),
    "action_id" : NumberLong(0),
    "transaction_id" : "ad77575a8b4f52e477682e712b1cbd884299468db6a94d909f90c6961cea9b02",
    "authorization" : [
            {
                    "permission" : "active",
                    "actor" : "eosio"
            }
    ],
    "handler_account_name" : "eosio.token",
    "name" : "transfer",
    "data" : {
            "from" : "eosio",
            "to" : "b1",
            "quantity" : "10.0000 EOS",
            "memo" : "Never doubt that a small group of thoughtful, committed citizens can change the world; indeed, it's the only thing that ever has - eosacknowledgments.io"
    },
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-07-10T15:15:41.750Z")}
```

I'm trying to create text index for string fields in "data" field. It can be done with

```
db.Actions.ensureIndex({"$**":"text"})
```

But according to mongo document here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/ this will create index on all text fields of the whole document, which is a waste.

Can I achieve the same index behavior, but only for text fields under "data"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [the official doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/) says,

> MongoDB provides text indexes to support text search queries on string content.
> Text indexes can include any field whose value is a string or an array of string elements.

But you don't have string or array of strings, but a json object.
The way to achieve what you want is to manually create your text index with every field of your data subdocument :

```
db.Actions.createIndex(
  { 
  "data.from" : "text", 
  "data.memo" : "text", 
  "data.quantity" : "text", 
  "data.to" : "text"
  }
)
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention all fields in "data" are dynamic, it's not always "from", "memo", "quantity", "to" but various from doc to doc. That's why I want to do text index in the first place.

Comment: you cannot do this on a json object, so the only way for you is to create a full document index with $** wildcard.

Comment: Another way can be to transform your object in an array of {k,v} pairs with aggregagtion framework and [$objectToArray stage](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/), out results in new collection and put index on that new collection, then query it... Can be useful for static collections, but all process need to be repeated to keep new collection up of date.

Comment: Yeah, that's a clever move ! Fortunately all those document will never change after being put. I thought I have to switch to elasticsearch. This can  definitely solve it.